# What do they mean by current specs in datasheet: peak or average value?

Tags: arduino, datasheet, mosfet-driver

I am using an Arduino DUE (Atmel SAM3X8E) to control my power MOSFET (IRLZ24N) through a Phtovoltaic MOSFET driver (Panasonic AVP1122).
While reading there respective datasheets, I've been noticed that they specify maximum currents but without precising if they are peak or average values.

From [Panasonic AVP1122 datasheet](https://b2b-api.panasonic.eu/file_stream/pids/fileversion/619):
[image]

From [Atmel SAM3X8E datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-11057-32-bit-cortex-m3-microcontroller-sam3x-sam3a_datasheet.pdf):

[image]
[image]

In addition, I am a bit confused about the max current supported by the SAM3X8E (LQFP package) under DC input voltage around 3.3V, the total DC output current (peak or average?) of all the used pins (sink+source?) should not exceed 130mA whereas the max continuous DC output current (peak or average?) for an individual pin is 150mA and 300mA peak when pulsed!

Answer (score 1):

Unless otherwise specified (which it is for the LED) assume that maximums are just that, you don't get more by running at lower duty cycle.

Additionally, absolute maximum ratings are NOT anywhere you want to be in operation, look for something like 'typical operating conditions' or such to se how you should be running the thing. I would bet on 3.3V for the IO and something like 10 or 20mA per pin, not to exceed specified total across all pins (Seldom an issue unless you are driving an LED matrix directly off the CPU, so don't do that!).

The total DC current number is probably related to the number of ground or IO power pins and the desire not to cause excessive IR drop or heating.

The 1.8V LDO supplies the core, it has little to do with the IO pins that ma be run at (typically 3.3V), this is the power for the CPU core itself, together with its memories and suchlike, it is not the rail that supplies the IO drivers.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheets are quite clear about their meaning. For the driver the peak current is specified as a rectangular waveform with a duty factor of 0.1% and a frequency of 100 Hz.

For the microcontroller the maximum values are clearly listed as DC values. By definition, DC values are neither "peak" or "average", they are constant. There is one specification for **I/O** pins and another for the **on-chip voltage regulator**. "Output current" means sourced current.

So, in neither case are these RMS currents.

Comment: But still can't find the max RMS current handled by individual pin.

Comment: Why would you **need** a specification for RMS current? Please describe the situation or circuit where the specifications you are given are not sufficient.

Comment: The max RMS current for an individual microcontroller pin will be the same as the maximum IO pin current. You do not get extra for lower duty cycle (or at least the manufacturer is not prepared to qualify the part for that). See table 45.2 in that horrid datasheet for the details IoL and IoH are the numbers you need. You must also respect the total maxim given in the abs max ratings section,....

Answer (score 1):

I think you already have a pretty good answer from Dan. But I'd like to inject a few thoughts into your head and, as it turns out, the text is excessive for comments. Besides, it may qualify as an answer of sorts. So perhaps it is appropriate here.

Dan's caution about sticking with what is specified and avoiding your own "interpretation" about what isn't specified is well-made. Manufacturers choose to write certain specifications because they believe it is important to their target market. But they also choose not to over-specify (because it means more testing and that adds expense to the parts that their target market may not be willing to accept.) They could. Because they do have a lot of information, in-house. But if they publish it then they may have to add cost to every part they ship. So the selection of published specifications are taken very seriously.

For some CPUs (and do not take this to mean *all*), there are port limitations. For example, there may be a port **A** with associated 8-bit registers. This port goes out to 8 pins on the device. And internally, there may be certain aluminum traces supplying that port's current requirements for all of its associated pins. In such a case, there may be a port limit that is independent of the pin limit. The port might be capable of \$100\:\text{mA}\$ and each pin may be capable of \$25\:\text{mA}\$. That would be based upon the aluminum traces to the port and then to each pin within the port. But this also means that you cannot expect to get \$8\cdot 25\:\text{mA}=200\:\text{mA}\$ out of the port. It's limited to \$100\:\text{mA}\$ because of other aluminum traces on the die. So you have to be wary of all of this -- if it is specified. They may, instead, choose to just say \$10\:\text{mA}\$ per port pin and leave it at that. But they would know (but they would not tell you) that you could use \$25\:\text{mA}\$ if you limited the other pins on that port. These kinds of details are important.

[Electromigration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromigration) is one of many limiting factors on all traces on the chip. A designer can go through all of this in detail with you, if you ask them. But if so, these conversations are NOT specifications. The designer can tell you what you can get away with. But they cannot tell you that you can rely upon it. That will be on your shoulders, if you decide to void the specifications they publish and instead choose to go your own way.

You can do some "interpretations" on your own. For example, you can read your Atmel SAM3X8E datasheet as telling you that they can handle about \$1\:\text{mA}\$ per I/O port pin and that the BGA is a little bit better than the LQFP in this regard (likely due to shorter binding wires.)

But that this relates only to the main power aluminum traces that supply everything else in the system. Within that, the DC characteristics will tell you about each port and port pin, in some cases. You can still expect the port pin details to be accurate. But you also have to keep in mind that they are all being supplied by some common traces that have their own (chip wide) limitations. So you have to take everything into account.

When not talking about DC, but say PWM, then there are different considerations. Not only is this about elecromigration (one problem that is directly related to current in the trace) but it is also about fusability (vaporization.) If you exceed the action integral of the aluminum traces, they literally will vaporize and your part is then dead.

This can happen even when the RMS current is within what you read as the DC specification. For example, you may find a specification that \$9\:\text{mA}\$ is the DC port pin maximum for some specific port pin. But this does *not* mean that you can pump \$900\:\text{mA}\$ for 1% of the time!!! If you do that, you will almost certainly fuse the device and it will cease to function. (The average of the current is useless, here.) This may also still fuse the traces when you PWM only 0.01% of the time. (RMS of \$900\:\text{mA}\$ pulses for 0.01% is equal to \$9\:\text{mA}\$.)

These fusing limits (action integral limits) are entirely separate from the DC current limits. And you cannot just blindly perform some over-simplified calculation here. These are entirely different things!

In short, don't assume. If you need to know, ask.

Most MCU devices do NOT specify their action integrals on their port pins or the shared port power traces, etc. In fact, most devices generally don't specify the action integral limits unless their device is intended to be used in such situations (such as fuses, which will have such specs, or wire-wound resistors which are often called upon for such service.)

So follow Dan's advice. Follow the specification where it exists and don't over-interpret things where it does not. If you need to know, then make a phone call or write a letter and ask. The manufacturer will try to help you out, 9 times out of 10. They want you to use their device. So if they can help, they will.